# Swift Adding-annotation action is repeating on the map when dragging

Tags: ios, swift

I am now currently learning how to add pins or annotations on a map with swift 2.0. I have done some research, and achieved the goal that an annotation will be added when the user long press on a location. However, there is a bug for my code, when I long press a spot, with a pin added, the adding-action will repeat itself if I do not release my finger and drag it on the screen. As shown in the picture
[repeated pins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfH4s.png)

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

let longPressingGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "addPinsOnMaps:")

longPressingGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.2

mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressingGesture)

}

func addPinsOnMaps(gesturePressing: UIGestureRecognizer){

    let touchPoint = gesturePressing.locationInView(self.mapView)

    mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.mapView)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.title = "This Place"
    annotation.subtitle = "Gonna stay here for a while"
    annotation.coordinate = coordinates
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: try setting longPressingGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.2 to 0

Comment: @FrancescStudio, thanks for the answer, but that does not work. I guess I did not make myself clear? As far as I am concerned, the minimumPressDuration property is for the minimum time when a gesture will be recognized. But my problem is that the fuction associated with the gesture does not end if I do not release my finger, which will cause the annotation to be created again and again. I hope that user can only create one annotation for one time of long pressing.

Comment: I ran a sample code and I came across the same problem you just need to add `UIGestureRecognizerState` function take a look at the answer I posted. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to need to add a `UIGestureRecognizerState` to check the gesture add this code before your action method.

```
func action(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        return
    }
```